# SSRS reports rendering strangely in IE 9

Tags: internet-explorer, reporting-services

I have noticed some odd behavior in my reports when viewed in IE9.  The right side is sort of cut off:
[image]

[image]

I've tried setting AsyncRender to true and false and get the same result.  The report looks fine and dandy in Safari, Chrome, and Firefox.  The report size is 8.5 x 11.  Is there some other option I need to set to get this thing to render properly in IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I wound up doing was changing my meta tag from

```
<meta content='IE=9,IE=10' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' />
```

to

```
<meta content='IE=EmulateIE8' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' />
```

and everything worked fine.

Comment: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">` Worked for me.