# How to emulate Iframe only in IE8 mode.

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, internet-explorer, iframe

The issue I have is the same as the 2 below:

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19981770/ssrs-reports-rendering-strangely-in-ie-9)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25557568/ssrs-reports-clipped-in-ie9-but-fine-in-ie8)

The problem I have is that my app is an AngularJS page which use ui-router which is not supported in IE8.

To be able to correctly display SSRS report I have to add this meta to the root page:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
```

But this cause lots of issues with page display, I need to find different solution.

I was trying something like the below, but no luck:

```
<iframe class="ssrs-frame" type="text/html" ng-src="{{trustSrc(SSRS.url)}}" frameborder="0">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there any way I could force Iframe only to emulate with IE8?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have specific CSS for IE8 you could use (inside head):

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8.css">
<![endif]-->
```

That works. I don't know if HTML also allows this, you should test it:

```
 <!--[if IE 8]><iframe></iframe><![endif]-->
```

Else you could create 2 iframes, 1 which you show for IE8 and 1 which does not. You could set `display: block` inside the `ie8.css` file for the specific iframe.

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: Or put a message in that conditional that tells users to use a different browser. Microsoft themselves don't even support IE8 any more

Comment: It is actually IE9 issue. Unfortunately this is browser which run on over 2k pc's in my company, so the message is not a solution.

Comment: @Whistler earlier versions of angular support IE9. What version are you using? Microsoft isn't supporting IE9 any more either BTW

Comment: Angular yes but not the ui-router. We will be rolling out IE 11 next year, I can't wait that long

Comment: If it a IE9 issue you could simply replace `IE 8` with `IE 9`? https://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/